# selectDialog with address bar instead of dropdown with Photoshop script

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

I'm writing a custom script for Photoshop to handle batch processing of images.  I have two input folders and an output folder that I need to specify.  Right now I'm using something like this to select my folders:

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder of  images to process");
```

Because I'm working on a server with a pretty deep folder hierarchy, it can be a real pain to select through the drop-down menu that Photoshop presents to me in this dialog.

[image: My target folder is actually much deeper than this...]

It would be so much easier to have a folder selection dialog with an address bar and quick access panel like this:

[image: So much easier to navigate!]

All other PS scripts that I've been digging around in use the `Folder.selectDialog` method to set file paths to a variable.  Is there a reason for this?  If not, then how can I instruct Photoshop the second style of folder navigation dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that Adobe supports this dialog as a folder selecting option.

There was a similar thread to this posted on the Adobe forums where a workaround was suggested:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1094128

The solution that was suggested is to use a `saveDialog` function instead of `selectFolder`.   This gives you the folder dialog that we want, but comes with the downside of having to type a dummy name into the filename path.  It also says "Save As" on the top of the dialog box, which is confusing.

Here's what was offered:

> by [lilsmokie](https://forums.adobe.com/people/lilsmokie) on Nov 8, 2012 2:19 PM
>
> ```
>  var dskTop = Folder.desktop;
>     var dskPth = String(dskTop);
>     var newSpot = new File(dskPth+"/poop");
>     var selectedFolder = newSpot.saveDlg('Select Destination Folder');
>     var illFilePath = selectedFolder.path;
>     alert(illFilePath);
> ```
>
> This opens the dialog at the desktop.  Then put "poop" or whatever you
>   like in the text field.  There the user can navigate to where ever. 
>   When they it save illFilePath will have the folder path.  Not perfect
>   but its close enough for me right now.

I've also discovered that I can set the starting location of the `selectDialog` by using `selectDlg` instead:

```
var outputFolder = Folder(app.activeDocument.path).selectDlg("Select a folder to output images to:");
```

This gives some control over the starting location so that the user doesn't have to click through a million dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your first screenshot you can see the unput text area `Folder: This PC`. It works just like an address bar. You can type (or paste) something like `\\server\work\folder\subfolder` into this area and you get this folder ('subfolder' in this case) immediately.

On MacOS this dialog doesn't show the `Folder: ...` input area. But you can press `Cmd-Shift-G` and get the native system 'address bar' anytime.